# How do i merge code after update table in yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I am using yii framework with PHP and MySQL. I am creating small application,then update one table and generate crud also.after generate crud, my previous codes are erased.I want know how to merge the codes after update the tables.

Comment: Can you provide some code how you create and erase `CRUD`

Comment: @Justinas : i using gii concept to create CRUD

Comment: If you are making only minor modifications to database, add them manually to files. Or if you code is also used everywhere else, modify CRUD templates.

Comment: if i used CRUD templates means all previous codes will be erased .for me dont want to erased previous code.

Comment: I see no other way. Either you put changes to your code manually or update Yii default templates with your code (what i think is not suitable for you). Better make full database design and only than make changes in code.

Comment: its Okay Justinas..I waiting for what i expect